# Tensorflow: Use case for determining a dose of medication

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm new to machine learning and trying to figure out where to start and how to apply it to my app.

My app is pulling a bunch of health metrics and based on all of them is suggesting a dose of medication (some abstract medication, doesn't matter) to take. Taking a medication is affecting health metrics and I can see if my suggestion was right of if it needs adjustments to be more precise the next time. Medications are being taken constantly so I have a lot of results and data to work with.

Does that seem like a good case for machine learning and using some of neural networks to train and make better predictions? If so - could you recommend an example for Tensorflow or Keras?

So far I only found image recognition examples and not sure how to apply similar algorithms to my problem.

Comment: Other Stack Exchange communities such as **Cross Validated** or **Data Science** might be more beneficial, given the audience

Answer (score 1):

I'm also a beginner into machine learning, but based on my knowledge, one way would be to use **supervised learning** with Keras, which uses Tensorflow as a backend. Keras is a lot easier to program than Tensorflow, but eventually Tensorflow might as well do the trick (depending on your familiarity with machine learning libraries).

You mentioned that your algorithm suggests medication based on data (from the patient).

One way to predict medication is to store all your preexisting data in a CSV file, and use the CSV module to read it. This tutorial covers the basics of reading CSV files (https://pythonprogramming.net/reading-csv-files-python-3/).

Next, you can store the data in a multi-dimensional array, and run a neural network through it. Just make sure that you have sufficiently enough data (the more the better) in comparison with the size of your neural network.

Another way, as you mentioned, would be using Convolutional Neural Networks, which theoretically could and should work, but I have very little experience programming them, so I'm afraid I can't give you any advice for that (you can program CNNs in both Keras and Tensorflow).

I do wish you good luck in your project!